# UICollectionView cells width based for iphone5 vs iphone6

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have implemented a UICollectionView which is a 2 column grid. I have implemented sizeForItemAtIndexPath methods like this

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(160, 180);
}
```

this works fine on iPhone5 but not on Iphone6 due to different pixel width (320 vs 357). Is there a way using AutoLayout to specify the width based on iPhone screen size or I have to manually check in the code and specify the correct width?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to set the width based on screen size. Search this site for one and try it. Then ask your question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simply

```
return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, 180);
```

Comment: thats code :) .. that was the question. do I have to do this in code. or is there any other way to do it in Storyboard in AutoLayout.

Comment: @g.revolution no, there's no way to do this in the storyboard. You can't set the size of a cell with auto layout.